# Android fragments: On Activity Created

Tags: java, android

I have a fragment and I am trying to save and restore states using the Bundle object and OnSaveInstanceState method.

My question is, will there be a problem using the OnActivityCreated call back method to do the check on the bundle and restore data if its a restored instance?

At the moment my OnCreateView contains all the code to carry out inflation (XML to java objects),initialises references to my child views (text view and buttons etc.), set on click listeners and some variables.

I was doing some research and I read that the order of fragment creation is 
OnAttach
OnCreate 
OnCreateView
OnActivityCreated
OnStart
OnResume

So I was thinking that since OnCreateView is called before OnActivityCreated allows the views and my variables to be initialised and there after check if its an restored instance. This is to prevent the null pointer exception from occurring.

Can you please give me advice if this is good practice. Im still learning android and lifecycles is probably my most weakest part to get a hang of.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The design is that you're supposed to do it in onRestoreInstanceState.  Doing it elsewhere is probably possible, but would make your code harder to understand from an outside perspective.